# How to remove some cms pages from sitmap.xml in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

**Hello Guys, how to remove some cms pages from sitemap.xml**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for it.
need to override sitemap model file.so first of all create **di.xml** file at your module directory

> `/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

and add below code in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Sitemap"/>
</config>
```

create "Sitemap.php" in "Vendor\Module\Model" and add below code

```
public function collectSitemapItems()
    {
        $helper = $this->_sitemapData;
        $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
        $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeId);
        $this->addSitemapItem(new DataObject(
            [
                'changefreq' => $helper->getCategoryChangefreq($storeId),
                'priority' => $helper->getCategoryPriority($storeId),
                'collection' => $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection($storeId),
            ]
        ));

        $this->addSitemapItem(new DataObject(
            [
                'changefreq' => $helper->getProductChangefreq($storeId),
                'priority' => $helper->getProductPriority($storeId),
                'collection' => $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection($storeId),
            ]
        ));

        $this->addSitemapItem(new DataObject(
            [
                'changefreq' => $helper->getPageChangefreq($storeId),
                'priority' => $helper->getPagePriority($storeId),
                'collection' => $this->_cmsFactory->create()->getCollection($storeId),
            ]
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need them at all, you can disable them.

Comment: thank you @diana  but I need it all in frontend. I posted answer so someone can use code.

Comment: roger that, glad you sorted it out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Magento 2.4, so I implemented a module to allow to select from backend with a flag which pages to exclude from sitemap.

First of all add a flag to the CMS pages table:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\SitemapExcludeCmsPage\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();

        $connection->addColumn(
            'cms_page',
            'exclude_from_sitemap',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => false,
                'comment' => 'Exclude from Sitemap'
            ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Then add it to the CMS page form `view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <fieldset name="search_engine_optimisation">
        <field name="exclude_from_sitemap" formElement="checkbox">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    <item name="toggleLabels" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="on" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Yes</item>
                        <item name="off" translate="true" xsi:type="string">No</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Exclude page from Sitemap</label>
                <dataScope>exclude_from_sitemap</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <checkbox>
                    <settings>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                        </valueMap>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                    </settings>
                </checkbox>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Clone in your module the class `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Cms\Page` to add the condition

```
    ->where('main_table.exclude_from_sitemap = 0')
```

in the `$select` variable of `getCollection` method (should be valid also simply to extend this class and override the method).

Now clone `\Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\CmsPage` class and change it to use your version of `Page`:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\SitemapExcludeCmsPage\Model\ItemProvider;

use Vendor\SitemapExcludeCmsPage\Model\PageFactory;
use Magento\Sitemap\Model\SitemapItemInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\CmsPageConfigReader;

class CmsPage implements \Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\ItemProviderInterface
{
    /** @var PageFactory */
    private $cmsPageFactory;

    /** @var SitemapItemInterfaceFactory */
    private $itemFactory;

    /** @var CmsPageConfigReader */
    private $configReader;

    /**
     * @param CmsPageConfigReader $configReader
     * @param PageFactory $cmsPageFactory
     * @param SitemapItemInterfaceFactory $itemFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CmsPageConfigReader $configReader,
        PageFactory $cmsPageFactory,
        SitemapItemInterfaceFactory $itemFactory
    ) {
        $this->cmsPageFactory = $cmsPageFactory;
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->configReader = $configReader;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getItems($storeId)
    {
        $collection = $this->cmsPageFactory->create()->getCollection($storeId);

        $items = array_map(function ($item) use ($storeId) {
            return $this->itemFactory->create([
                'url' => $item->getUrl(),
                'updatedAt' => $item->getUpdatedAt(),
                'images' => $item->getImages(),
                'priority' => $this->configReader->getPriority($storeId),
                'changeFrequency' => $this->configReader->getChangeFrequency($storeId),
            ]);
        }, $collection);

        return $items;
    }
}
```

and set it as preference in `etc/di.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sitemap\Model\ItemProvider\CmsPage" type="Vendor\SitemapExcludeCmsPage\Model\ItemProvider\CmsPage" />
</config>
```

Finally update the database and compile the classes:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento c:c
```