# Magento2 Ignore specific URLs from XML sitemap

Tags: magento2, sitemaps

Magento2 I need to remove some specific URLs from sitemap. How can I achieve this?

I am using default Magento XML sitemap generater

Comment: Here is my answer please check it https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/336917/how-to-remove-some-cms-pages-from-sitmap-xml-in-magento-2 Hope it helps you

Comment: @GohilRajesh suppose I want to exclude this URL then - site.com/blog/category/root then how can I achieve this?

Comment: blog is custom module?